# Annotation processor needs to generate Classes that i can use in my general code

Tags: java, annotations, generator

I'm creating a Annotation processor for MQTT. This processor will be used like this

```
@MQTT(subscription = "/move/forward")
public void moveForward() {
    mobility.moveForward();
}
```

So when i build my project it needs to create a Super class with the correct code. And the working will be like. Publish on the "/move/forward" topic. Then execute this method. 
At this time he generates the code for this but then I need to get access to this class. But I can't get access to it. Here below you can see where and how I generate the files. I use java poet for it.

```
  JavaFile javaFile = JavaFile.builder(getPackage(classname), genClass.build())
                .build();

        try{
            javaFile.writeTo(processingEnv.getFiler());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Here you can see that I use now the filer object from the processingEnv. But then he generates the files in the target directory. But I need them in /src/generated. How can i do that?